# Grouping files based on their filename and keeping only one out of the group?

Tags: regex, bash, recursion, grouping, filenames

I have a bunch of files in several folders with names in the form NumA_NumB_NumC.jpg (ex: 1000_5000_001.jpg). For every NumA there is one or more NumB. And for every NumB there are several NumC. for each NumA_NumB group, I just want to keep only the lowest NumC.

So for example:

- 1000_5000_001.jpg <- keep
- 1000_5000_002.jpg <- delete
- 1000_5000_003.jpg <- delete
- 1000_5001_032.jpg <- keep
- 1000_5001_033.jpg <- delete

(note: there is no regularity to the NumB numbers, except that the lowest one in each group is the one to keep)

What's the best way to do this? I was thinking linux shell script with regular expressions, but the syntax is a bit over my head right now. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I can't see the connection on what you _say_ you want, and deleting `1000_5002_033.jpg`, as it is a unique NumA_NumB with the lowest NumC?

Comment: That was a typo - thanks for catching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sort + awk

```
ls *.jpg|sort -t_ -k1.1n -k2.2n -k3.3n |awk -F _ '!a[$1 FS $2]++'

1000_5000_001.jpg
1000_5001_032.jpg
```

If your sort command has `-V` option

```
   -V, --version-sort
          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

you can have shorter one:

```
ls *.jpg|sort -V  |awk -F _ '!a[$1 FS $2]++'
```

Comment: Thanks to let me know. You need vote it up or accept it, if this answer fixs your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name '*_*_*.jpg' -printf "%f %p\n" | 
awk '{split($1, a, "_"); if (seen[a[1],a[2]]++ == 0) {$1=""; print}}' | 
xargs echo rm
```